# How to order objects by foreign key existance in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following database structure

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Related(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Tables are filled with following data

```
[
{"pk": 1, "model": "app.item", "fields": {"pub_date": "2014-09-04T05:31:35.126Z"}}, 
{"pk": 2, "model": "app.item", "fields": {"pub_date": "2014-09-04T05:31:37.733Z"}}, 
{"pk": 3, "model": "app.item", "fields": {"pub_date": "2014-09-04T05:31:38.039Z"}}, 

{"pk": 1, "model": "app.related", "fields": {"item": 1}}, 
{"pk": 2, "model": "app.related", "fields": {"item": 2}}, 
{"pk": 3, "model": "app.related", "fields": {"item": 1}}
]
```

I need to select **Item** objects ordered by **Related** objects existance (count > 0). Closest query syntax I know is:

```
Item.objects.order_by('-related', '-pub_date')
for item in Item.objects.order_by('-related', '-pub_date'):
    print('%s %s' % (item.pub_date, item.related_set.count()))
```

What we need (ordering is not affected by related objects count):

```
2014-09-04 05:31:37.733000+00:00 1
2014-09-04 05:31:35.126000+00:00 2
2014-09-04 05:31:35.126000+00:00 2
2014-09-04 05:31:38.039000+00:00 0
```

What we get:

```
2014-09-04 05:31:35.126000+00:00 2
2014-09-04 05:31:37.733000+00:00 1
2014-09-04 05:31:35.126000+00:00 2
2014-09-04 05:31:38.039000+00:00 0
```

In terms of SQL is what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM app_item
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_related ON ( app_item.id = app_related.item_id )
GROUP BY app_item.id
ORDER BY COUNT(app_related.id) > 0 DESC, app_item.pub_date DESC
```

Or something like this:

```
Item.objects.annotate(has_related=CountGreaterZero('related')).order_by('-has_related', '-pub_date')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

**UPDATED** after comments.

As far as i know, using django ORM it can be done using 2 queries. And another solution is using [raw sql query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), in that case you'll need only one.

Here is django solution, but it will execute two queries:

For given models:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from itertools import chain

>>> for item in chain(Item.objects.annotate(num_related=Count('related')).filter(num_related__gt=0).order_by('-pub_date'), Item.objects.annotate(num_related=Count('related')).filter(num_related=0).order_by('-pub_date')):
>>>     print item.pub_date, item.num_related
2014-09-04 06:40:54.175445+00:00 1
2014-09-04 06:40:53.336461+00:00 2
2014-09-04 06:40:54.607874+00:00 0
```

Comment: Such query gives us:  
  
`2014-09-04 05:31:35.126000+00:00 2  
2014-09-04 05:31:37.733000+00:00 1  
2014-09-04 05:31:38.039000+00:00 0`

First place takes item with more related objects count. Order what I need:

`2014-09-04 05:31:37.733000+00:00 1  
2014-09-04 05:31:35.126000+00:00 2  
2014-09-04 05:31:38.039000+00:00 0`

So I need something like this
    Item.objects.annotate(has_related=Exists('related')).order_by('-has_related', '-pub_date')

Comment: @mofr in that case use `order_by('num_related')`, and not `order_by('-num_related')`. In your question you wanted a DESCending order, so i set a descending order. Looks like you realy want an ASCending order.

Comment: @mofr, i've updated the answer after you comment. Is it ok now? If so, you better clarify you question.

Comment: Items with `num_related > 0` should be ordered by `pub_date` field. Other items (with no related objects) should be included in the result (but after items with num_related>0) and ordered by `pub_date` too.

Comment: Ordering, as you can see, is `.order_by('num_related', '-pub_date')`. You want just `.order_by('-pub_date')`?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't really use it. First reason is that my real ordering looks like `order_by=['-priority', '-has_related', '-pub_date']`. And the second problem `object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()`.